# ArrayList final in android

Tags: java, android, arraylist, final

I want to make my ArrayList with custom objects final so that the objects cannot be changed after they are set.

I tried to declare it like this:

```
private final ArrayList<Datapoint> XML = new ArrayList<Datapoint>();
```

I fill the ArrayList with this lines:

```
FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(f);
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
XML = (ArrayList<Datapoint>) in.readObject();
in.close();
fileIn.close();
```

and this for-loop to show the objects:

```
for(int i=0;i<XML.size();i++){
                    item = XML.get(i);      
                    parsedData = parsedData + "----->\n";
                    parsedData = parsedData + "Name: " + item.getName() + "\n";
                    parsedData = parsedData + "stateBased: " + item.getStateBased() + "\n";
                    parsedData = parsedData + "mainNumber: " + item.getMainNumber() + "\n";
                    parsedData = parsedData + "dptID: "+ item.getDptID() + "\n";
                    parsedData = parsedData + "Groupadress: "+ item.getGroupadress() + "\n";
                    parsedData = parsedData + "priority: "+ item.getPriority() + "\n";
                }
```

xmlOutput.setText(parsedData);

But Eclipse says `The final field XMLDetailsActivity.XML cannot be assigned`.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`final` keyword just mean that the reference to the object cannot be changed. It does not mean however that you cannot call the object's method that changes its state.

This can be achieved for list by using `Collections.unmodifiableList()`.

Comment: ok I will take a look at the `Collections.unmodifiableList()` but I never used that before...

Comment: ah there is a misspelling in your post, it should be `Collections.unmodifiableList()`. Plaease edit it, because with the correct spelling I was able to find some other links in stackoverflow. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your XML variable is `final`, and yet you try to assign it another value: 
`XML = ...in.readObject();` You can't do that.

Also, note that a final ArrayList means you can't replace the ArrayList, you can still call its methods to modify its content, final is not C++'s `const`.

Comment: if I delete the global declaration and change the line to `final ArrayList<Datapoint>XML = (ArrayList<Datapoint>) in.readObject();`, the for-loop cannot resolve XML...

Answer (score 0):

Once the `final` variable has been assigned a value, you can no longer assign another value.

The `final` member variables must be assigned values before the constructor of the class they belong to has finished executing.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign a new value to your XML variable. As you declare it final before this, you cannot reassign it.